# How to Register Solr with Eureka

Tags: solr, integration, netflix-eureka

I have 2 Spring apps ("client-app" and "service-app") that are already registered to Eureka (and talk via Feign Client). However, I have to talk to an instance of Solr and I'm forced to hard-code the IP address in the properties file. I would much rather not do this and use Eureka for service-discovery.

**Question**: Is there a way/plugin to have solr register itself with Eureka, so that clients can then discover it (even if it's programmatically via a start-up listener or some sort)?

I've looked at the solr API and it doesn't seem to have lifecycle listener (onStartUp or onShutdown hooks)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You would need a [Solr Plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins) for this, which is [SolrCore aware](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#SolrCoreAware). That interface method `inform` is called anytime something interesting happens with a core. Within the implementation of the inform method you would need to register/deregister as a client.

Then you would need to add it to your [Solr (Cloud) instance](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Adding+Custom+Plugins+in+SolrCloud+Mode). After that and proper configuration of your plugin, it should work.

Comment: I will see if I can create a stub to upload it to github.